# LinkedList remove(int from, int to) method

Tags: java, doubly-linked-list

Since a node is defined mostly by its links (next and previous), removing a set of nodes is mostly the same as removing just one node. You have a chain -1-2-3-4-5- and you remove some of the links: -1  2-3-4  5-.

```
public LinkedList<Elem<E>> remove(int from, int to) 
{
    Elem<E> left = head;      
    for (int i=0; i < from; i++) 
    {
        left = left.next;

    }
    Elem<E> right = left;
    for(int i = 0; i< to - from; i++){
      right = right.next;
    }
    // removing the elements from the list;
    left.next = right;
    right.previous = left;
    size -= to - from;

    //left to right are still linked, so just shove them into
    //a new linkedlist and return.
    LinkedList<Elem<E>> ret = new LinkedList<Elem<E>>();
    ret.head = left;
    ret.tail = right;
    return ret;
}
```

Test class:

```
import junit.framework.Assert;
import junit.framework.TestCase;
import junit.framework.TestSuite;

public class TestAll extends TestCase {

    public static void testRemoveStart() {

 List<Integer> l1, l2;

 l1 = new LinkedList<Integer>();

 for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
     l1.add(i);
 }

 l2 = l1.remove(0, 4);

 Assert.assertEquals(5, l2.size());

 for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
     Assert.assertEquals(new Integer(i), l2.get(i));
 }

 Assert.assertEquals(5, l1.size());

 for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
     Assert.assertEquals(new Integer(i+5), l1.get(i));
 }

    }

    public static void testRemoveMiddle() {

 List<Integer> l1, l2;

 l1 = new LinkedList<Integer>();

 for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
     l1.add(i);
 }

 l2 = l1.remove(3, 7);

 Assert.assertEquals(5, l2.size());

 for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
     Assert.assertEquals(new Integer(i+3), l2.get(i));
 }

 Assert.assertEquals(5, l1.size());

 for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
     Assert.assertEquals(new Integer(i), l1.get(i));
 }

 for (int i=3; i<5; i++) {
     Assert.assertEquals(new Integer(i+5), l1.get(i));
 }

    }

    public static void testRemoveLast() {

 List<Integer> l1, l2;

 l1 = new LinkedList<Integer>();

 for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
     l1.add(i);
 }

 l2 = l1.remove(5, 9);

 Assert.assertEquals(5, l2.size());

 for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
     Assert.assertEquals(new Integer(i+5), l2.get(i));
 }

 Assert.assertEquals(5, l1.size());

 for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
     Assert.assertEquals(new Integer(i), l1.get(i));
 }

    }

    public static void testRemoveOne() {

 List<Integer> l1, l2;

 l1 = new LinkedList<Integer>();

 for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
     l1.add(i);
 }

 l2 = l1.remove(5, 5);

 Assert.assertEquals(1, l2.size());

 Assert.assertEquals(new Integer(5), l2.get(0));

 Assert.assertEquals(9, l1.size());

 for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
     Assert.assertEquals(new Integer(i), l1.get(i));
 }

 for (int i=5; i<9; i++) {
     Assert.assertEquals(new Integer(i+1), l1.get(i));
 }

    }

    public static void testExceptions() {

 List<Integer> l;

 l = new LinkedList<Integer>();

 for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
     l.add(i);
 }

 boolean flag = false;
 try {
     l.remove(-5, -1);
 } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
     flag = true;
 } catch (Exception e) {
     ;
 }
 Assert.assertTrue(flag);

 for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
     Assert.assertEquals(new Integer(i), l.get(i));
 }

 flag = false;
 try {
     l.remove(-1, 5);
 } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
     flag = true;
 } catch (Exception e) {
     ;
 }
 Assert.assertTrue(flag);

 for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
     Assert.assertEquals(new Integer(i), l.get(i));
 }

 flag = false;
 try {
     l.remove(0, 10);
 } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
     flag = true;
 } catch (Exception e) {
     ;
 }
 Assert.assertTrue(flag);

 for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
     Assert.assertEquals(new Integer(i), l.get(i));
 }

 flag = false;
 try {
     l.remove(5, 4);
 } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
     flag = true;
 } catch (Exception e) {
     ;
 }
 Assert.assertTrue(flag);

 for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
     Assert.assertEquals(new Integer(i), l.get(i));
 }

    }


    /**
     * Runs the test suite using the textual runner.
     */

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
 TestSuite suite = new TestSuite();
 suite.addTestSuite( TestAll.class );
 junit.textui.TestRunner.run( suite );
    }

}
```

Below is the errors I get:

5 tests failed:
  TestAll
    testRemoveStart
    testRemoveMiddle
    testRemoveLast
    testRemoveOne
    testExceptions
File: C:\Users\Mikros0ft\Google Drive\Semester 2\ITI1121\Assignment 4\3\TestAll.java  [line: 30]
Failure: junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: expected:<5> but was:<4>
File: C:\Users\Mikros0ft\Google Drive\Semester 2\ITI1121\Assignment 4\3\TestAll.java  [line: 56]
Failure: junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: expected:<5> but was:<10>
File: C:\Users\Mikros0ft\Google Drive\Semester 2\ITI1121\Assignment 4\3\TestAll.java  [line: 86]
Failure: junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: expected:<5> but was:<14>
File: C:\Users\Mikros0ft\Google Drive\Semester 2\ITI1121\Assignment 4\3\TestAll.java  [line: 112]
Failure: junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: expected:<1> but was:<10>
File: C:\Users\Mikros0ft\Google Drive\Semester 2\ITI1121\Assignment 4\3\TestAll.java  [line: 146]
Failure: junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: null

Comment: Its basically the same principle, except that after locating the first removal point, you will iterate another `to - from - 1` nodes, then perform the same kind of node reassignment that you did in the original remove method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since a node is defined mostly by its links (next and previous), removing a set of nodes is mostly the same as removing just one node. You have a chain -1-2-3-4-5- and you remove some of the links: -1  2-3-4  5-.

```
public LinkedList<Elem<E>> remove(int from, int to) 
{
    Elem<E> left = head;      
    for (int i=0; i < from; i++) 
    {
        left = left.next;

    }
    Elem<E> right = left;
    for(int i = 0; i< to - from; i++){
      right = right.next;
    }
    // removing the elements from the list;
    left.next = right;
    right.previous = left;
    size -= ((to - from)+1);

    //left to right are still linked, so just shove them into
    //a new linkedlist and return.
    LinkedList<E> ret = new LinkedList<E>();
    ret.head = left;
    ret.tail = right;
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: this seems like it would work. Only problem is that I am not keeping track of the tail.

Comment: well, "left" still holds its next which still has its own next and etc.
Essentially, the idea is that even though you remove these nodes from the main linkedlist, they are in themselves another linkedlist, which is all you need to return.

Comment: So this is what I have for the end of the method:

`LinkedList<E> ret = new LinkedList<E>();` 
    `ret.head = left;`
    `ret.size=to+from;`
    `return ret;`

For some reason, it is not matching my expected results.

Comment: how is it not matching? is the original array the items were removed from correct or is the extracted linkedlist messed up in some way?

Comment: Woops, I edited your answer instead of editing my question. Sorry about that. Anyways, I have posted my testcase and the results I received. Thanks!

Comment: ret.size should be (to - from+1), should it not? If I am extracting element 3 through 7 inclusive, then i emit 3, 4, 5, 6, 7.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, `from` and `to` are both inclusive, replace this

```
Elem<E> right = left.next.next;
```

by

```
Elem<E> right = left.next;
for (int i = 0; i <= to - from; i++)
    right = right.next
```

`size` also changes.

```
size -= to - from + 1
```

Everything else remains the same.